# Code Only Runs When Stepping Through Code - Race Condition?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that seems to work when I step through the code using F8, but not when I try to run the entire sub or call it from a button the user will push in the Worksheet.

When I run the code in its entirety, I can tell it does some of the steps, but not all of them.

I have read a couple existing posts about this happening and it seems like everytime the person was using alot of `.Select` `.Activate` and so on. I am not using those commands, and I tried to set my sheets and variables more dynamically than that. I also included `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Since I'm not using those types of commands, I'm assuming it is some sort of Race Condition, where it needs more time to pause. I tried adding a couple `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` lines, but when I added those to the VBA code it would just freeze Excel entirely when I tried running the entire code. Not sure why it did that, but I would have to kill Excel in the Task Manager.

Here is the VBA, sorry for all the comments I added:

```
Sub CombineExcels()
'***** This sub is to autofilter for each available filter option and put the matching Excel file paths into one cell on the FINAl sheet *****

UserForm1.Show vbModeless

'***** Setting variables *****
Dim RngOne As Range, cell As Range
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim LastCellC As Long
Dim Row As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim s As String
Dim EnterVal As Range
Dim FirstUsedRow As Long
Dim FirstEmptyCell As Long

'***** In the event of an error, we will skip to our Error Handler *****
On Error GoTo EH

'***** Turn off Excel Screen Updating so the screen doesn't keep flashing and slow the macro *****
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'***** Finding the last used row, first empty row, and largest range that we will work with *****
With Sheets("Final")
    LastCell = .Range("A" & Sheets("Final").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCellC = .Range("C" & Sheets("Final").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set RngOne = .Range("A2:A" & LastCell)
End With

'***** This section is a loop that will apply the filter for each option and combine the results onto the Final sheet *****
For Each cell In RngOne
    With Sheets("Folder Output")
        '***** If a filter is already applied, we will remove the filter *****
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        '***** Clearing any remaining data from the location we will temporarily store file paths in *****
        Worksheets("Final").Range("Q1:Q100").Clear
        '***** Apply the filter. The criteria is named CELL which is a loop for each filter option *****
        .Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell
        '***** Find the last row of filter results in Column C *****
        Row = .Range("C" & Sheets("Folder Output").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        '***** If the row number returned is 2 then we know that there is only 1 file path result *****
        If Row = "2" Then Row = .Range("C" & Sheets("Folder Output").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        '***** Setting a new range for only the filtered results in Column C *****
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Dim rngCell As Range
            '***** Loop to get each result and place it on the FINAL sheet in column Q for now *****
            For Each rngCell In rng
                    If Sheets("Final").Range("Q1").Value = "" Then
                        FirstEmptyCell = .Range("Q" & Sheets("Final").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
                        Worksheets("Final").Range("Q" & FirstEmptyCell) = rngCell.Value
                    Else
                        FirstEmptyCell = .Range("Q" & Sheets("Final").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        Worksheets("Final").Range("Q" & FirstEmptyCell) = rngCell.Value
                    End If
            '***** Continue to the next filtered result until all file paths for that filter are complete *****
            Next rngCell

        '***** Finding the last used row from the pasted file path results in Column Q *****
        count = Sheets("Final").Cells(Rows.count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        '***** Loop to combine all the paths into one string but separate the paths with a ; *****
        For i = 1 To count
            If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then s = s & Cells(i, 17).Value & ";"
        Next
            '***** Find the last used row from Column C in the Final sheet. Then paste the combined file paths to Column C *****
            Set EnterVal = Worksheets("Final").Range("C" & LastCellC)
            EnterVal.Value = s
            Set EnterVal = Nothing
            s = ""
        '***** This tells the macro to move a row down next time through the loop *****
        LastCellC = LastCellC + 1
    End With
Next

'***** Once the loop is finished, we will end this sub in the CleanUp section *****
GoTo CleanUp

'***** Before exiting the sub we will turn Screen Updating back on and notify the user the Excel file paths are combined *****
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    UserForm1.Hide
    MsgBox ("Excel File Paths Have Been Concatenated!")
Exit Sub
'***** If an error occurs during the loop, we go here to redirect to turn updating on and end the sub *****
EH:
    ' Do error handling
    GoTo CleanUp

End Sub
```

I can tell that when I run the entire code it is doing all the filtering, and I believe putting the results in Column Q on the "Final" worksheet, but those results are not being merged together with the ; as a delimiter and then being put in Column C as one string containing multiple paths.

So I think the issue is happening somewhere around here, but not sure:

```
'***** Finding the last used row from the pasted file path results in Column Q *****
        count = Sheets("Final").Cells(Rows.count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
        '***** Loop to combine all the paths into one string but separate the paths with a ; *****
        For i = 1 To count
            If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then s = s & Cells(i, 17).Value & ";"
        Next
            '***** Find the last used row from Column C in the Final sheet. Then paste the combined file paths to Column C *****
            Set EnterVal = Worksheets("Final").Range("C" & LastCellC)
            EnterVal.Value = s
            Set EnterVal = Nothing
            s = ""
        '***** This tells the macro to move a row down next time through the loop *****
        LastCellC = LastCellC + 1
    End With
Next
```

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You do not specify the Worksheet in your i=1 to count loop

Comment: Without knowing the total values that the variables might be, have you tried using Long instead of Integer for all of your related variables?  Probably not related to the qeustions, but not bad practice as the # of rows in Excel can exceed Integer storage.

Comment: VBA runs synchronously on a single thread - a race condition is unlikely ;-)

Comment: @DarrellH I had noticed a few qualification issues myself, so +1 to you on that.  Didn't mean to steal your thunder there with my answer, though we were on a similar path!

Comment: @Cyril there are about 550 possible filter items, and some have multiple lines. So around 1500 total rows. Perhaps changing to Long could help.

Comment: @Cyril I changed the Integers to Long and it still didn't fully work when I ran it using F5. But then I pushed F5 a second time when the first attempt finished, and it worked then. So not sure why it works sometimes and not all times?

Comment: @DarrellH do you mean at the `Set EnterVal = Worksheets("Final").Range("C" & LastCellC)` part? When I removed specifing the worksheet it seemed to "work", in regards to putting information in cells that it wasnt doing before, but the information was all incorrect and for some reason it was putting in 3 semicolons instead of one.

Comment: @TBoulz Long versus Integer may have helped something move along, but it was not the fix to the problem... what sheet was active when you ran the macro?  My guess is that one of the unqualified sheets in your code was the sheet you had active and as such the code ran by counting or finding the appropriate row on that Active sheet.  if you don't specify a sheet, VBA uses the active one.

Comment: As Mathieu didn't I suggest OP using [RubberDuck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) to check code for flaws like  implicit refs, etc.

Comment: @TBoulz In your code `For i = 1 To count
            If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then s = s & Cells(i, 17).Value & ";"` you don't specify the worksheet prior to `Cells`.  When you step through the code you are probably on that worksheet, which is why it works.  When you initiate the code from another location it will not.  Always provide the most detail for your objects to avoid whatever sheet is active from being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu shouldfully qualify your references:

```
count = Sheets("Final").Cells(Rows.count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
```

Should be:

```
With Sheets("Final)
    count = .Cells(.Rows.count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
End with
```

Similarly in above areas, you have added qualifications when using a with statement:

```
Row = .Range("C" & Sheets("Folder Output").Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row '.Rows.Count as sheet is already qualified
```

Comment: If multiple workbooks are involved, `Sheets` (or `Worksheets`) should also be qualified with an explicit `Workbook` object, too.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks Mat's Mug; I hadn't seen any in the post, but it's always a good thing to point out!

Comment: @Cyril thank you for the tip, I update my code to reflect this at the Count section. I had the same result. First 2 times I ran F5, it didnt fully work. Then the 3rd time it worked.

Comment: @TBoulz Verify ALL of the qualifications... even *If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" Then s = s & Cells(i, 17).Value & ";"* is bad as you have unqualified cells().  Just looks like a lot of oversights.  once you get those qualifications sorted, that should be what fixes it.  Same as my comment to the main post, depending on the active sheet, certain counts may seem correct, but using appropriate qualifications removes that dependence.

Comment: @Cyril okay I did that. I put everything under the same `With Sheets("Final")` that you mentioned above, and just moved the `End With` to after the loop finishes and it seems to have worked. Strangely, I run an identical Sub after this one to do the exact same thing but use a different worksheet to get PDF files instead of Excel files, and even making the changes that worked for the Excels,  it seems to not work for the PDFs. I've run out of time to look work on this today, but will resume tomorrow to see if I missed something.

Comment: @TBoulz if the posted question for the Excel side is complete, and the Answer provided got you there, please mark as Accepted, then ask a new question for the PDF related macro.  That will help keep things a bit cleaner for the existing question and getting the correct info retained for anyone else who looks at this post for help.

Comment: @Cyril done. Thank you very much for your assistance.